# How to get the Seconds from Date - Swift 4

Tags: swift, date, timestamp

I am trying to get the number of SECONDS between two Dates.
for an example having a date like this:

```
let savedDate = Jun 25, 2018 at 12:48:09 AM -> (just printed as example date)
let currentDate = Date()
```

Can anyone help me understand how to find the number of second passed as a Double preferably?

Answer (score 2):

[`Date#timeIntervalSince(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince) is probably what you're looking for.

## Playground Example...

I modified the format so it would parse, but the basic concept works.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"
let date = formatter.date(from: "Jun 25, 2018 12:48:09 AM")
if let date = date {
    Date().timeIntervalSince(date)
}
```

Will output

```
29793.5867500305
```